# Customer ID is null in Observer when customer_save_after triggers

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.2.5

I have this event that fires just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_after">
        <observer name="remago_addcustomertotree" instance="Remago\Customertree\Observer\Addcustomertotree" />
    </event>
</config>
```

What I am trying to do is get the customer ID so that it can be added in a different table, **when I create it in backend**.

This is how I do it:

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

Now, I am able to get all of his/her data by using

```
$customer->getName()
```

or

```
$customer->getAddress()
```

and everything looks ok.

The problem is I can't seem to get anything other than null when I use:

```
$customer->getId()
```

or

```
$customer->getEntityId()
```

or

```
$customer->getData('entity_id')
```

Initially, I thought the problem was that I was using the event

```
customer_save_before
```

But changing it to

```
customer_save_after
```

had no effects whatsoever.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi. You are trying observer event in M1 or M2?

Comment: Hi Raj, I'm using M2

Comment: flashed cache after event changing ?.....

Comment: I thought I did, but I did a cache:flush and now it's working flawlessly. Thanks Minesh, what a n00b I am!

Comment: :P)...............

Comment: Are you using a die() statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `customer_save_after_data_object` event instead.

In Magento 2.2, it is dispatched here: `htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php:239`

```
public function save(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer, 
    $passwordHash = null
)
{
    // Other customer save logic has been removed for brevity

    $savedCustomer = $this->get($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_save_after_data_object',
        ['customer_data_object' => $savedCustomer, 'orig_customer_data_object' => $customer]
    );
    return $savedCustomer;
}
```

See `htdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/adminhtml/events.xml:13` for an implementation example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_after_data_object">
        <observer name="customer" instance="Magento\Quote\Observer\Backend\CustomerQuoteObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Doing a cache:flush (which I thought I did, but it turned out I didn't) solved the problem. But I am in fact still using customer_save_after. Do you think I should use the one you suggested? Why is customer_save_after working if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @LucaD.R. `customer_save_after` doesn't appear to exist in the Magento version I was using to check (2.2.0) - perhaps it does in yours? You didn't specify a complete version after all.

Comment: @LucaD.R. You should use the event which is most appropriate to your circumstances. Review both, then use the best fit for your extension.

Comment: I'm using Magento ver. 2.2.5

Comment: @LucaD.R. If your current solution (to use `customer_save_after`) is working for you, then I'd stick with that.